# ARM GCC 10.3 & 13.x - invalid parameter for a function pointer with -Os

Tags: gcc, arm, cortex-m

In *Cortex-M7*, I have a function, compiled with `-Os`, that is in the specific address, and I call it through the function pointer, like so (`+1` is for thumb mode):

```
    //Some code above...
    memset(.....)

    uint32_t (*caller)(uint32_t taskid, ...);
    caller = (uint32_t(*)(uint32_t, ...))((uint32_t)0x08020000 + 1U);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        caller(i);
    }
```

Function gets called `3` times and returns, but `i` parameter inside the function is not `0,1,2`, but rather `garbage,0,1`. This is not the case if I do not use `-Os` compiler option.

Inspecting disassembly, it seems that for loop is unrolled, with `movs r0, #1` and `movs r0, #2`, and it was even re-ordered.

```
    memset(shared_ram, 0x00, sizeof(*shared_ram));
 8000968:   2000        movs    r0, #0
        caller(i);
 800096a:   4d1a        ldr r5, [pc, #104]  ; (80009d4 <main+0xc0>)
    memset(shared_ram, 0x00, sizeof(*shared_ram));
 800096c:   6018        str r0, [r3, #0]
 800096e:   6058        str r0, [r3, #4]
 8000970:   6098        str r0, [r3, #8]
        caller(i);
 8000972:   47a8        blx r5
 8000974:   2001        movs    r0, #1
 8000976:   47a8        blx r5
 8000978:   2002        movs    r0, #2
 800097a:   47a8        blx r5
```

Is this a compiler bug?

Cortex-M7 cache is not enabled, if that matters.

Compilation flags:

```
-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections --specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections  -g -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -Og -g3 -ggdb -fno-eliminate-unused-debug-symbols -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Os -std=gnu11
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The disassembly looks fine to me.  Unrolling the loop is perfectly legitimate.  The compiler decided to use the zero in `r0` both for the `memset` and to pass to the `caller` function, but there's nothing wrong with that either.  Is there something specific you think is not right about the generated code?

Comment: @NateEldredge function that get's called first time, doesn't receive `0` as a parameter.

Comment: You mention gcc 10.3 and 13.x in the title - is the problem reproducible with both of them?

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes, with both of them. And as it is embedded specific, I'm not able to easily reproduce for non-MCU code. I checked godbolt, but code looks "fine".

Comment: Yes, that's what you said, but the disassembly shows 0 being passed correctly.  If something is corrupting the register in between (misbehaving interrupt or exception handler??), well, that's possible, but it's not the compiler's fault.  If that's really the code which the compiler generated, then whatever else this may be, it's not a compiler bug.

Comment: Here the simple code, it looks like in this case memset is called before ldr r0, #0: https://godbolt.org/z/18q54TWzM.
And there is no issue when `-Os` is not used. Something is strange indeed

Comment: Yeah, but both ways are fine.  I'm not sure why you attach so much importance to the reordering of the `memset` as I can't see how it would make any difference.

Comment: My point here now is that code on godbolt hasn't been equally compiled. I'll try to figure out reasons based on the code before/later.

Comment: Here's a really wild guess: the stores to `data` cause a page fault (or some other similar exception), and your page fault handler has a bug where it fails to preserve `r0`.  So when the compiler does the `memset` first and then initializes `r0`, you don't see a problem.  But when it does them in the opposite order, even though that would be fine in normal circumstances, you get the corrupted value.

Comment: @NateEldredge problem found. inside my function, I had identical case branches, and compiler didn't bother even to read the parameter from `r0`, instead it used whatever value was on stack for the variable at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not linked to compiler (99.9% the case). My function included identical branches, therefore compiler chose `default` way and didn't bother with variable value.

```c
__attribute__((section(".security_secure_gate")))
uint32_t se_secure_gate(uint32_t id, ...) {
    switch (id) {
        case 0: {
            __NOP();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            __NOP();
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```